# Remove what follows Nth occurrence Using one-liners

Tags: perl, sed, awk, gawk, nawk

I would like to remove what follows the forth occurrence of the character ":" in any field contains it. See the example:

Input:

```
1 10975     A C    1/1:137,105:245:99:1007,102,0   0/1:219,27:248:20:222,0,20 
1 19938     T TA   ./.                             1/1:0,167:167:99:4432,422,0,12,12
12 20043112 C G    1/2:3,5,0:15:92                 2/2:3,15:20:8
```

Expected output:

```
1 10975     A C    1/1:137,105:245:99   0/1:219,27:248:20 
1 19938     T TA   ./.                  1/1:0,167:167:99
12 20043112 C G    1/2:3,5,0:15:92      2/2:3,15:20:8
```

So Basically any field that has ":", what follows its forth occurrence should be removed. Note that the third line nothing change because ":" appears three times only. I have tried and found a solution (not good) which didn't work only for the first line and not the secod as it has more commas ","

Incomplete Solution:

```
sed 's/:[0-9]*,[0-9]*,[0-9]*//g'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On fields 5 through to the last field, this will remove the fourth occurrence of the regexp `:[^:]+`

```
< file.txt awk '{ for (i=5; i<=NF; i++) $i = gensub(/:[^:]+/, "", 4, $i) }1' | column -t
```

On fields 5 through to the last field, this will remove everything after the fourth `:`

```
< file awk '{ for (i=5; i<=NF; i++) $i = gensub(/((:[^:]+){3}).*/, "\\1", 1, $i) }1' | column -t
```

**Explanation:**

Upon re-reading your question, the second solution is probably what you're looking for. The first solution looks for a colon followed by one or more characters not a colon and removes them. The third argument to `gensub()` describes which match of the regexp to replace. So a 4 tells `gensub()` to remove the fourth match of the pattern. The second solution, looks for three sets of the regexp described in the first answer. At this point it's worth mentioning that `gensub()` provides an additional feature that is not available using `sub()` or `gsub()`. This is the ability to specify components of a regexp in the replacement text, much like how other languages use parentheses to perform capturing. `gensub()` is a very powerful command only available using GNU awk. The description and example provided [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) are very useful. HTH.

Results:

```
1   10975     A  C   1/1:137,105:245:99  0/1:219,27:248:20
1   19938     T  TA  ./.                 1/1:0,167:167:99
12  20043112  C  G   1/2:3,5,0:15:92     2/2:3,15:20:8
```

Comment: Also, if you want tab separated output, just change `| column -t` to `OFS="\t"`

Comment: Thanks V much it works. Can you please explain the gensub command and what is the difference between gensub, sub, and gsub ?

Comment: @user1421408: I have added some explanation regarding these commands. Please see the comments. HTH.

Answer (score 5):

Sed:

```
sed -r 's/((:[^: \t]*){3}):[^ \t]*/\1/g' file | column -t
```

Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/((:\S*){3}):\S*/$1/g' file | column -t
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`

```
sed -r 's/((:[^ ]*){3}):[^ ]*/\1/g' file
```

Output:

```
1 10975     A C    1/1:137,105:245:99   0/1:219,27:248:20 
1 19938     T TA   ./.                             1/1:0,167:167:99
12 20043112 C G    1/2:3,5,0:15:92                 2/2:3,15:20:8
```

---

Using `perl`

```
perl -pe 's/((:\S*){3}):\S*/$1/g' file
```

Comment: Why not `perl -pe 's/((:\S*){3}):\S*/$1/g'` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lane 's/(.*?:.*?:.*?:.*?):.*/$1/g  for @F ; printf "@F"."\n"' your_file
```